# Exporting excel with custom headings and multiple sheets in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to export using laravel excel where I have custom headers. Somewhat like this:

[image]

I'm using laravel excel 3 using FromQuery, WithTitle, WithHeadings.

I'm able to achieve half of the desired output using withheadings array, but the remaining part is unachievable

```
<?php

    namespace App\Exports;

    use Modules\Report\Entities\Aereport;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

    class AereportPerDaySheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize
    {
        private $year;
        private $day;
        private $month;

        public function __construct(int $year, int $month, int $day)
        {
            $this->year = $year;
            $this->day = $day;
            $this->month  = $month;
        }

        /**
         * @return Builder
         */
        public function query()
        {   
            return     Aereport::select('report_id','dateofreport','date','url','username','reportertype','productname','verbatim','priority','aeraised')->whereMonth('dateofreport', $this->month)->whereday('dateofreport', $this->day);

        }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        return $this->day .' '. date("F", mktime(0,0,0,$this->month,1)) .' '. $this->year;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return[
            'Id',
            'Date issue was found',
            'URL',
            'Username',
            'Reporter Type',
            'Product Name',
            'Verbatim',
            'Priority',                        
        ];
    }
}
```

[image]

As shown I'm able to get headers but not the said customizations.

Comment: Have you tried using the view -> excel export option. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html. You can create a html table in a blade view and export it directly to excel.

Comment: I thought of the same, but I also want to export with multiple sheets. Any clue on how to achieve this using view? Or something else?